# approximate algorithm for top-k query in hive?

Tags: algorithm, hive, approximate

everyone,in hive ,we use

```
select word,count(*) as cnt from table group by word order by cnt limit N
```

for top-N query.

As we kown the speed is not fast,i learn about some approximate algorithm for top-k query ,such as countsketch algorithm or another algorithm.

Could we add approximate algorithm to hive for speed up top-k query?